# Why Conda cannot call correct Python version after activating the environment?

Tags: python, anaconda

I have the following conda environment under Linux:

```
$ conda info -e
# conda environments:
#
py33                     /u21/coyotito/.anaconda/envs/py33
root                  *  /u21/coyotito/.anaconda
```

And `py33` is created with this command:

```
$ conda create -n py33 python=3.3 anaconda
```

The problem is when I activate `py33` it still cannot call Python version 3.3.

```
[coyotito@pearl ~]$ source activate py33
(coyotito)[coyotito@pearl ~]$ python --version
Python 2.7.10 :: Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)
(coyotito)[coyotito@pearl ~]$ conda info -e
# conda environments:
#
py33                     /u21/coyotito/.anaconda/envs/py33
root                  *  /u21/coyotito/.anaconda
```

Namely it still calling old python. Notice also that the prompt under bracket is not `(py33)`.

```
(coyotito)[coyotito@pearl ~]$ which python
~/.anaconda/bin/python
```

Instead of python in new environment:

```
~/.anaconda/envs/py33/bin/python3.3
```

How can I resolve this issue?

**Update**

My PATH environment in `~/.bash_profile` looks like this:

```
export PATH=$HOME/.anaconda/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: This is strange. If you get an error when typing `source deactivate` may be a sign that you have two concurrent versions of anaconda one in an environment? Maybe this is what is creating problems?

Comment: When you are in your root conda environment what does `which activate` return?

Comment: @Paul: `$HOME/bin/activate`

Comment: Same happens to me when I create an environment for 2.7, when I use a more modern python 3.4 anaconda : / I need 2.7 for an online course, which still didn't update their material.

Answer (score 84):

I had the exact same problem. Not sure what I did to get into that mess, but I solved it with a simple:

```
conda deactivate
conda activate foo_env
```

(If you have activated multiple environments, you may need to run `conda deactivate` multiple times, including deactivating the "base" environment.)

Comment: I can confirm, but do you know why exactly do we need to deactivate ?

Comment: In my case, the problem happened after installing new packages. `conda` was "forgetting" it was using a different python version.

Comment: Just make sure you exit the default 'base' environment too.

Comment: what @JerryAjay said saved me, conda will load 'base' environment by default when terminal initializes. Screwed up my whole path.

Comment: O oh... this is not the first time I'm here. This does solve it and I don't understand what causes it. So that I don't come back another time I added to my .zshrc: `function condaenv() { conda deactivate; conda activate $1;}` and use `condaenv <MY_ENV>`

Comment: @JerryAjay That was it for me

Comment: You are my sweetheart @Tahlor. I was struggling for 6-8 hours. Your simple hack resolved my issue.

Comment: For me it showed (base) at the beginning of the shell line. With this solution it was removed and I was able to activate my specific one.

Answer (score 52):

TLDR;

```
# deactivate Conda environment
# (until even base environment is deactivated)
conda deactivate
# activate your environment
conda activate your_env_name_goes_here
```

try this

Activate an environment A and then check the location of Python package by using the command below.

> python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"

or as suggested in the comments

> which python

Activate another environment, let's say environment B and rerun the above python command. If conda isn't using the correct Python version then most likely running the above command will print the same path in both environments.

My conda installation wasn't using the correct version because I had activated my environment on top of the conda base environment.

Deactivating the base environment and then activating the environment I wanted, worked.

Conda calls this nested activation and you could read more about it in the [docs](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#nested-activation).

If you wanted to Disable Nested Activation

```
conda config --set auto_stack 0
```

If you wanted to Disable Base Env Activation

```
conda config --set auto_activate_base false
```

Comment: This really helped. I first deactivated my current env, then deactivated base env, and then reactivated my env. Worked.

Comment: Yes, deactivating all the environments did the trick for me.

Comment: This worked for me, I did not notice I was activating from the base environment until running across this answer. All good now.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! still, this is strange, I don't get the same behavior on fedora. If I activate the env on top of the base env, it changes as it should.

Comment: this worked for me as well. is there to change the default setting such that the base environment is not activated to start with?

Comment: Another way (on Unix) to check which python you're using: `which python`. Also useful for pip problems.

Answer (score 11):

Landed here with this same issue, but by moving out of the anaconda executable directory, the correct python was called. I was in a directory that contained the python executable that was installed with Anaconda2.

Example:

```
(py35) C:\Anaconda>python --version
Python 2.7.11 :: Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)

(py35) C:\Anaconda>cd ..

(py35) C:\>python --version
Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)

(py35) C:\>
```

Comment: thank god finally I got to know this after wasting hours, everything was correct once I moved to another directory: )

Comment: Besides the documented security reason, this example is another justification for not keeping "." in your PATH environment, if you are using any of *NIX based operating systems.

Answer (score 6):

This only happens when you create an environment without specifying any additional packages. I am using Conda 4.10.3

Refer https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9392#issuecomment-696897058

The following comment from the above link worked in my case:

> I noticed that it works if i install a packet when i create the environment.

```
antony@antony-fedora : ~/Workspace/tmp : which python /usr/bin/python
antony@antony-fedora : ~/Workspace/tmp : conda create --name my_env 
antony@antony-fedora : ~/Workspace/tmp : conda activate my_env 
(my_env) antony@antony-fedora : ~/Workspace/tmp : which python
/usr/bin/python 
(my_env) antony@antony-fedora : ~/Workspace/tmp : conda create --name my_env pip  
(my_env) antony@antony-fedora : ~/Workspace/tmp : conda activate my_env 
(my_env) antony@antony-fedora : ~/Workspace/tmp : which python ~/anaconda3/envs/my_env/bin/python
```

Also, recommend adding conda deactivate to the end of your `.zshenv` or `.bash_profile`

Answer (score 5):

So in my situation, a intern before me append anaconda path to path variable in `/etc/profile`, which override my conda setting in `~/.bashrc`, simply removing those line in `/etc/profile` can help.

Comment: I was my own intern, this was messed up on the back of me trying to fix pyenv. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and solved it by defining the Python version

```
conda create --name env_name python=3.10
```

instead of

```
conda create --name env_name
```

Answer (score 1):

With MacOS, I was facing a similar issue. I was able to resolve the issue by changing the python interpreter (appears on bottom left corner) within VS-code.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with macOS Ventura 13.2.1.
This was caused by vscode which first activates base then the specified environment. As it has already been suggested

```
# deactivate Conda environment
# (until even base environment is deactivated)
conda deactivate
# activate your environment
conda activate your_env_name_goes_here
```

also worked but didn't quite solve the problem since I had to do this every time I opened a vscode terminal.
The real problem is that there is no python in the base environment installed so I switched into the base env

```
# deactivate Conda environment
# (until even base environment is deactivated)
conda deactivate
# activate your environment
conda activate base
```

Then install python with

```
conda install python=3.10 #for example
```

I also had a `permission denied` error there so I made sure the specific folder had correct access writes before trying again

```
sudo chmod a+rwx <path_to_miniconda> 
conda install python=3.10 #for example
```

> NOTE: you probably don't need to have the `x` in `a+rwx` but I've only tested it this way

PS: I also had some aliases configured in my `.zshrc` (or `.bashrc` if you use bash) which I had to remove

```
alias python=python3
alias pip=pip3
```

then it worked like a charm!

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

For me on macos, I found that by setting my  `condarc` to activate base fixed the problem.

```
auto_activate_base: true
```

As an aside, and as others have noted elsewhere, it's good policy to deactivate `base` before activating another conda env.