# Using conda to create virtual environment, I get the wrong version of Python despite specifying version. Why?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, installation, virtualenv, conda

I need a virtual environment with Python 3.5, so I can run some tensorflow projects (tensorflow doesn't work on Python 3.6, which I normally use). I use conda because (as you'll see) I'm so bad at unix/understanding my computer.

I type in

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.5
```

and then

```
activate myenv
```

and then, to check, Python version,

```
python -V
```

The reply is **Python 3.6** which is not the one I want.

Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45293436/how-to-specify-python-version-used-to-create-virtual-environment), it seems like I need to install Python 3.5 outside of the virtual environment in order to call it, but how do I do that without messing with my installation of Python 3.6?

I get that this is a basic question but I'm terrible at computers and would be so grateful for any replies. Talk to me like I'm a child bc that's basically the level I'm on.

Comment: Tensorflow works on python 3.6 on all platforms at least since TF 1.2. Are you working with a TF version earlier than that?

Comment: @user1735003 I'm using pip install and that installs TF version 0.12. It says it's successfully installed, but when I open python and try to import TF, it says "No module named Tensorflow"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out what was wrong (sort of) by looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36733179/why-conda-cannot-call-correct-python-version-after-activating-the-environment). If i typed in

```
cd ..
```

to go one step up in the folder struction, and then checked my Python version, I had the right version (Python 3.5). From there I could install tensorflow and it was imported to python without problem. I have no idea why, but it works so I can't complain.