# VSCode Mac shows incorrect interpreter even after activation of environment

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, terminal

#### Problem

I am new to VSCode so I was trying to use the existing conda environments as part of my project in VSCode. I was able to use `Shift+Cmd+P` to select the relevant interpreter

> (in this case named `mlops`, as visible at the bottom right of the
> image below)

[image]

I was able to test that after selecting the interpreter, my code was actually using this, as displayed in the left side terminal window using the code below -

```
import sys
print("Interpreter:")
print(sys.executable)
```

Finally, I then went to another bash terminal (right side) and activated the conda environment. But, when I checked `which python` it still points to the wrong interpreter.

---

#### Attempts

I have gone through a large number of questions and solutions to solve this issue and most of them point to adding `terminal.integrated.inheritEnv` as `False` in the `settings.json`

But it doesn't seem to fix the issue.

My question is 2 fold:

1. Why is this happening and is this only a mac/Linux issue?
2. How do I fix this, in general, for my current and future projects?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60180578/5730738

Answer (score -1):

This is a common problem. **Switching between different environments** will lead to confusion in the environment.

What we need to do is to **deactivate all environments and then reactivating conda environment**.

You can refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60180578/18359438) which is the same to your problem for more information.