# Unable to import database module from firebase_admin

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-admin

I'm simply trying to add the Firebase Admin SDK to my Python script, but am unable to import the database module due to a TypeError in one of the library's python scripts.

I installed the library [as instructed](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup):

```
sudo pip install firebase-admin
```

I initialized the Firebase Admin SDK [as instructed](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start):

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db
```

But it breaks:

```
>>> import firebase_admin
>>> from firebase_admin import credentials
>>> from firebase_admin import db
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/firebase_admin/db.py", line 33, in <module>
    from firebase_admin import _http_client
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/firebase_admin/_http_client.py", line 30, in <module>
    raise_on_status=False, backoff_factor=0.5)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'status'
```

I peeked into the problematic script `_http_client.py` and saw that it imports `requests`, so I updated that with pip, to no avail.

No idea what could be the problem here. Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: What's your version of urllib3? Looks like your version's `util.retry.Retry` class does not yet accept the `status` argument. Maybe try to update that package as well.

Comment: @shmee I was at 1.22 before, upgraded to 1.24.1 at your suggestion, but still got the same error message.

Comment: Um ... seeing that your program runs in an anaconda env and that you used pip for the upgrade, I have to ask: are you sure that you did the upgrades on the correct interpreter version?

Comment: I'm... pretty sure? 
```Requirement already up-to-date: urllib3 in /anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (1.24.1)```

Comment: Yeah, OK :) Please don't mind the question. Still, unless I absolutely miss sth. here, the exception raises when `requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry.Retry` is instantiated in `_http_client`. I wonder if maybe sth. is messing up `sys.path` in that env. Could you please run a script that just does `import requests; print(requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry.__file__)` in that same interpreter and verify that it in fact imports the module from the urllib3 package in `/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30456573/why-has-anaconda-added-my-default-python-paths-to-the-specific-environments-pat this _might_ be related

Comment: Ha no worries, I was just scared that the problem really was that obvious. But it does look like it's importing from the same package: ```/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/retry.py```

Comment: Printing sys.path returns ten paths to ```/anaconda/lib/python3.6/``` and one path to ```/Users/jxu2/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages```. Could that be the problem? Sorry you have to hold my hand through this :/

Comment: No need to apologize. I actually find this quite an interesting problem ;) Yes, that one path to `/Users` might actually cause the issue. Do you have the environment variable `PYTHONPATH` set in the environment of that user jxu2? If so, try to unset it. If not, `conda info -a` might help identifying the origin of that entry. However, I'm a bit puzzled that the `retry` module appears to be located directly in the `requests` package. I would have expected it to be `/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py`.

Comment: Otherwise, it would be interesting to see if the class `Retry` in `/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/retry.py` actually takes an argument `status` in its `__init__` method.

Comment: Nooope, PYTHONPATH isn't set in jxu2. As for the ```__init___``` method in ```retry.py```, it accepts the following arguments: ```self, total=10, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None,
                 method_whitelist=DEFAULT_METHOD_WHITELIST, status_forcelist=None,
                 backoff_factor=0, raise_on_redirect=True, raise_on_status=True,
                 history=None, respect_retry_after_header=True```

Comment: That sure looks like an old `urllib3` version. The `status` option has been added in this PR nearly 2 years ago: https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/pull/1148. It has first appeared in the 1.21.0 release as far as I can tell: https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/1.21/urllib3/util/retry.py#L152

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, there was an old version of `urllib3` lurking in my `requests` package. Removing the former from the latter did the trick. Thanks to [shmee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4134674/shmee) and [Hiranya Jayathilaka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5190886/hiranya-jayathilaka) for leading me to the solution!

Comment: Huh? Now I wonder how an outdated urllib3 package ended up directly in `requests`. Normally, `packages` is a module that does some import wizardry to localize 3rd party packages ... oh well :) Cool that you found it!

Comment: @shmee I have no idea, my environment is probably a disaster (due to a decade of countless attempts to learn various programming languages). Hence my somehow using pip and anaconda simultaneously... anyway, thanks so much for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Leaving an answer here to help people who are googling this find it easily.

[Link to issue 262 on GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python/issues/262)

You can check your version with:

```
import requests
from requests.packages import urllib3
print(urllib3.__version__)
>>>"1.16.1" # my output
```

You can check the location of the urllib3 you are using with:

```
import requests
from requests.packages import urllib3
print(urllib3.__file__)
>>>'...anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/__init__.py'
```

If you are using Anaconda, you can physically remove the package, or you can just run `conda update urllib3` in a terminal. That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me , i just searched for the location of urllib3 package and then i deleted it . 
you can find the location of the package by taping the following commands in python interpreter

```
from requests.packages import urllib3
print (urllib3.__file__)
```